# How to enable build configuration Visual Studio 2010 express

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I enable the marked configurations in vb.net project?

Reason: I have differnent configuration (controlled by preprocessor statements) which should have different assembly names.

[image]

Comment: those configurations are set by default and can not be changed as long as you are developing for Windows.

Comment: It's a while since I've used VB Express and I don't have it available to test anywhere but, as far as I recall, you don't set them. The IDE just chooses a Debug or Release build depending on how you initiate it and that's all your options. VB Express has a reduced feature set so there are various things it can't do.  You probably ought to be upgrading to the Community edition of a later version.  It is still free and has pretty much all the features of the Professional edition, plus it can load 2010 projects and solutions without making changes, if I recall correctly.